# Увеличение вознаграждения после открытия конкурса

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Возможно ли увеличить премию в конкурсном вопросе после его открытия?

Comment: Вроде бы никак, но модератор может отменить конкурс (репутация вернётся), после чего вы сможете его переоткрыть. Но нужно ли это? Мне кажется, удвоение награды не удвоит приток "посетителей" в вопрос.

Comment: Понял. Тогда буду ждать.